# Can istio circuit breaker stop traffic for only one upstream server?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, circuit-breaker

I have been tested OutlierDetection for one upstream pod. I expected that istio prevents request goes to target upstream pod.

My test environment:

- Tested on docker-desktop, k8s, istio, github + argocd
- Target upstream pod always returns 500 http status and logs the request.
- Requests were repeatedly sent within another pod like this: `while [ true ]; do date; curl -v 'http://http-echo-svc.trafficmgmt:80/500'; sleep 1; done`
- DestinationRule yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: dr-status-echo
spec:
  host: http-echo-svc.trafficmgmt
  trafficPolicy:
    outlierDetection:
      consecutive5xxErrors: 6
      interval: 30s
      baseEjectionTime: 2m 
      maxEjectionPercent: 100
      minHealthPercent: 0
```

And pod & service yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: status-echo
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: echo-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: status-echo
      image: status-echo:0.0.3
      imagePullPolicy: Never
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8087
          name: http-echo-port
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: http-echo-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: echo-pod
  ports:
    - name: http-echo
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: http-echo-port
```

Upstream pod logged every requests. That means circuit breaker was not working.

Does OutlierDetection not work for one upstream or is my configuration wrong?

Comment: As described [here](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/upstream/outlier), Outlier detection and ejection is the process of dynamically determining whether some number of hosts in an upstream cluster are performing unlike the others and removing them from the healthy load balancing set.

Comment: So, when you have a single upstream host it might not work as expected. Can you explain your architecture and reason behind using outliner detection for a single upstream host when there much simpler solutions like kubernetes ingress, this will help us in understanding your case much better and to propose a better solution.

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni Thank you for answers. This test condition is not same with service environment. We has two circuit breaker requirement. First, we need to cut off traffic to the external api. We suppose that can be implemented by ServiceEntry. Second, we need to cut off traffic to an inernal service that is consist of many pods. The point of two requirements are cutting off whole traffic and I tried to test both in the single test with the condition "maxEjectionPercent 100%" especially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration looks right; I tried with the `fake-service` and configured it to always return 500.

Here's my configuration (that's equivalent to what you have, with the exception of different image):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: status-echo
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: echo-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: fake-service
      image: nicholasjackson/fake-service:v0.25.2
      env:
        - name: ERROR_RATE
          value: "1"
        - name: ERROR_CODE
          value: "500"
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      ports:
        - containerPort: 9090
          name: http-echo-port
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: http-echo-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: echo-pod
  ports:
    - name: http-echo
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9090
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: dr-status-echo
spec:
  host: http-echo-svc
  trafficPolicy:
    outlierDetection:
      consecutive5xxErrors: 6
      interval: 30s
      baseEjectionTime: 2m 
      maxEjectionPercent: 100
      minHealthPercent: 0
```

I am running curl from within a pod inside the cluster and on the first 6 tries, this is the response I get from the `status-echo` pod:

```bash
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< date: Wed, 26 Jul 2023 20:35:18 GMT
< content-length: 164
< content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 4
< server: envoy
<
{
  "name": "Service",
  "uri": "/",
  "type": "HTTP",
  "ip_addresses": [
    "10.42.0.64"
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "error": "Service error automatically injected"
}
```

On the 7th request, the response changes and looks like this:

```
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
< content-length: 19
< content-type: text/plain
< date: Wed, 26 Jul 2023 20:35:55 GMT
< server: envoy
<
* Connection #0 to host http-echo-svc left intact
no healthy upstream
```

Which basically means that the outlier detection kicked in and ejected the one failing host (hence the `no healthy upstream` response). Similarly, if you look at the logs from the istio-proxy (on the client side), you'll see a similar error:

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 UH no_healthy_upstream
```